# Why is this form not posting data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have the following form to post messages in a database. However, whenever I hit the input button it just freezes up and nothing happens. Can't seem to locate the exact issue. Tried changing the PHP to `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` and the submit button works fine, so I'm thinking it may be an issue with "textarea" settings. Anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

HTML:

```
<div id="message" class="messagearea">
    <form action="javascript:sendPM();" name="pmForm" id="pmForm" method="post">

                <input name="pm_send_id" id="pm_send_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user['userID']; ?>" />
                <input name="pm_send_name" id="pm_send_name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user['userName']; ?>" />
                <input name="pm_receive_id" id="pm_receive_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>" />
                <input name="pm_receive_name" id="pm_receive_name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['userName']; ?>" />
                <input name="pm_timesent" id="pm_timesent" type="hidden" value="" />
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">x</a>
        <h2>Send A Message</h2>
                <div id="interaction"></div>
                <br>
                <p>Message:</p>
                <textarea name="pmTextArea" id="pmTextArea"></textarea>
                <p>Attach A Video:</p>
                <input name="pmSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#pmForm').submit(function(){$('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled','disabled');});
  function sendPM(){
    var pmTextArea = $("#pmTextArea");
    var sendName = $("#pm_send_name");
    var sendID = $("#pm_send_id");
    var receiveName = $("#pm_receive_name");
    var receiveID = $("#pm_receive_id");
    var timesent = $("#pm_timesent");
    var url = "messages.php";
    if (pmTextArea.val() == ""){
      $("#interaction").html('Comment field is empty.').show().fadeOut(5000);
    }
    else {
    $.post(url,{ message: pmTextArea.val(), sendername: sendName.val(), senderid: sendID.val(), recname: receiveName.val(), recID: receiveID.val(), time: timesent.val()  },    function(data){
      $("#interaction").html('Message sent successfully.').show().fadeOut(5000);
      document.pmForm.pmTextArea.value='';
      });
    }
  }

</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.channel.php';
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

$user_message = new USER();

if (isset($_POST['message'])) {

  $to = ($_POST['recID']);
  $from = ($_POST['senderid']);
  $toName = ($_POST['recname']);
  $fromName = ($_POST['sendername']);
  $msg = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
  $time = ($_POST['time']);
  $avatar = ($_SESSION['avatar']);

  $stmt = $user_message->runQuery("INSERT INTO inbox(send_id, receive_id, send_name, rec_name, comment, timesent, avatar) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bindValue(1,$from);
  $stmt->bindValue(2,$to);
  $stmt->bindValue(3,$fromName);
  $stmt->bindValue(4,$toName);
  $stmt->bindValue(5,$msg);
  $stmt->bindValue(6,$time);
  $stmt->bindValue(7,$avatar);
  $stmt->execute();

}

?>
```

Comment: Remove `action="javascript:sendPM();"` and just do what you want in your `$('#pmForm').submit(function(e) { //...your code  })` callback instead. Just don't forget to add `e.preventDefault();` in the callback to stop the normal form behaviour.

Comment: A couple of things that I would like to point out. (i) The `action` attribute of the `form` tag `<form action="" >`is supposed to be the URL to which you want to submit the data to. By default, if this attribute is missing, it defaults to the current URL. If you want to invoke a JavaScript function upon submit, you can invoke it as a callback to the submit event. `action="javascript:sendPM();"` is not the appropriate place for it. (ii) Checking `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` is actually a better way to validate the page submit on the server-side (PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't need to invoke js from the form tag:

```
<form action="javascript:sendPM();" name="pmForm" id="pmForm" method="post">
```

becomes:

```
<form name="pmForm" id="pmForm" method="post">
```

Then hook the event to the submit button and simplify your js:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    var pmTextArea = $("#pmTextArea");
    var sendName = $("#pm_send_name");
    var sendID = $("#pm_send_id");
    var receiveName = $("#pm_receive_name");
    var receiveID = $("#pm_receive_id");
    var timesent = $("#pm_timesent");
    var url = "messages.php";
    if (pmTextArea.val() == ""){
      $("#interaction").html('Comment field is empty.').show().fadeOut(5000);
    }
    else {
    $.post(url,{ message: pmTextArea.val(), sendername: sendName.val(), senderid: sendID.val(), recname: receiveName.val(), recID: receiveID.val(), time: timesent.val()  },    function(data){
      $("#interaction").html('Message sent successfully.').show().fadeOut(5000);
      document.pmForm.pmTextArea.value='';
      });
    }
});
```

You don't need the function you defined. Also note the e.preventDefault that prevent the form from the default submit action.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the below lines

```
<form action="javascript:sendPM();" name="pmForm" id="pmForm" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" name="pmForm" id="pmForm" method="post">
```

and

```
$('#pmForm').submit(function(){$('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled','disabled');});
  function sendPM(){
    var pmTextArea = $("#pmTextArea");
    var sendName = $("#pm_send_name");
    var sendID = $("#pm_send_id");
    var receiveName = $("#pm_receive_name");
    var receiveID = $("#pm_receive_id");
    var timesent = $("#pm_timesent");
    var url = "messages.php";
    if (pmTextArea.val() == ""){
      $("#interaction").html('Comment field is empty.').show().fadeOut(5000);
    }
    else {
    $.post(url,{ message: pmTextArea.val(), sendername: sendName.val(), senderid: sendID.val(), recname: receiveName.val(), recID: receiveID.val(), time: timesent.val()  },    function(data){
      $("#interaction").html('Message sent successfully.').show().fadeOut(5000);
      document.pmForm.pmTextArea.value='';
      });
    }
  }
```

to

```
    $(document).on('submit','#pmForm',function() {
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled','disabled');

    var pmTextArea = $("#pmTextArea");
    var sendName = $("#pm_send_name");
    var sendID = $("#pm_send_id");
    var receiveName = $("#pm_receive_name");
    var receiveID = $("#pm_receive_id");
    var timesent = $("#pm_timesent");
    var url = "messages.php";
    if (pmTextArea.val() == "") {
      $("#interaction").html('Comment field is empty.').show().fadeOut(5000);
    }
    else {
      var data = { message: pmTextArea.val(), sendername: sendName.val(), senderid: sendID.val(), recname: receiveName.val(), recID: receiveID.val(), time: timesent.val()  };
      $.post(url,data,    function(data){
      $("#interaction").html('Message sent successfully.').show().fadeOut(5000);
      document.pmForm.pmTextArea.value='';
      });
    }
});
```

Please let me know if it didn't worked. Thanks

Comment: was that helpful?

Comment: replace if (isset($_POST['message'])) { with if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

Comment: Please open the page in firefox browser, press ctrl_shift+q and go to the network tab. Below that , you can find the xhr tab. Hit the submit button and tel me if any xhr request is fired.

Comment: have you tried it? you can do the same in chrome browser also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161500/discussion-between-bimal-kumar-and-cordell).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code snippet. Worked fine in my machine. Hope it works

```
$(document).on('submit','#pmForm',function() {
        $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled','disabled');

        var pmTextArea = $("#pmTextArea");
        var sendName = $("#pm_send_name");
        var sendID = $("#pm_send_id");
        var receiveName = $("#pm_receive_name");
        var receiveID = $("#pm_receive_id");
        var timesent = $("#pm_timesent");
        var url = "messages.php";
        if (pmTextArea.val() == "") {
          $("#interaction").html('Comment field is empty.').show().fadeOut(5000);
        }
        else {
          var data = { message: pmTextArea.val(), sendername: sendName.val(), senderid: sendID.val(), recname: receiveName.val(), recID: receiveID.val(), time: timesent.val()  };
          $.post(url,data,    function(data){
          $("#interaction").html('Message sent successfully.').show().fadeOut(5000);
          document.pmForm.pmTextArea.value='';
          });
        }
    });
```

Comment: How about this?

Answer (score 0):

Change you js-code to that one:

```
$('#pmForm').submit(function(e){
    // prevent default event handler
    e.preventDefault();
    // disable input
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    // call your function
    sendPM()
 });
```

And then you could make the action attribute of your form empty. Just:

```
<form action="" name="pmForm" id="pmForm">
```

You don't actually need these attributes if you make all the magic by your own in js.

But if you want to support browsers without javascript, you should add "action" and "method" attributes according to your API urls. So if user's browser will support JS all these attrubutes will be ignored, but for others guys your form will work in a native way.